# Query firebase .startAfter todays date

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a query that selects and displays all 'Upcoming' schedule appointments for a specific user and orders them by date. I would also like it to select the documents where the date is today and later.

```
return this.afs.collection('schedule', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', id).orderBy('date').startAfter(Timestamp)).snapshotChanges();
```

The query works fine without the '.startAfter', but I cannot seem to get that portion to work. .
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Show me the log.

Comment: `startAfter` is for pagination and not for general queries.  Are you trying to do pagination here?

Comment: no, not trying to use pagination

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return this.afs.collection('schedule', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', id)
.orderBy('date')
.where("date", ">", Timestamp)
.snapshotChanges();
```

Comment: I get this error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a function
FirebaseError: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a function

Comment: send me screenshots of firebase database

Comment: yes technically my answer is correct. Please set it as a correct answer if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
today = new Date();
```

then...

```
return this.afs.collection('schedule', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', id).orderBy('date').where("date", ">=", this.today).snapshotChanges()
```